# автозапуск программы python

Tags: python

есть программа, скомпилированная далее в .exe файл

пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы если оно было активно, то при перезапуске пк, автоматически открывалось

придумал такой вариант:

программа стартанула, записала себя в автозапуск, перед "нормальным" завершением работы программы она удалила себя из автозапуска.

как сделать так, чтобы программа сама себя добавила в автозапуск и при нормальном завершении удалила себя оттуда?

код программы:

```
import tkinter
master = tkinter.Tk()
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(master, bg='blue', height=300, width=600)
canvas.pack()
master.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ну смотря где. В винде есть реестр и есть директория куда можно ссылку положить. Это как минимум

Comment: @alex на windows

Comment: @Андр По дефолту на английской винде по этому пути C:\ Users\ Имя_пользователя\AppData\ Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup . При этом если буддешь искать вручную учти, что AppData скрытая папка - надо в Виде указать показывать скрытые папки и файлы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```py
import sys
import os
import tkinter

path = sys.argv[0]
file_name = path.split('\\')[-1]
startup_path = '"%Appdata%\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\"'

os.system(f'copy {path} {startup_path}') # копируем себя

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.mainloop()

os.system(f'del {startup_path+file_name}') # удаляем себя
```

Comment: а вот удаление себя просто теперь можно в определенные условия поставить?

Comment: @Андр вполне, например проверить время можно или еще что. но если оставить так, то "само удалится" при завершении работы "как положено"